# How to navigate to updates section in iTunes from an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, itunes

In my iphone app I just want to navigate to updates section of iTunes so that a user can see the updated version of my app. I am trying to do it with following line

```
NSString* link = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=My_App_Id&mt=8";  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

It takes me to the iTunes but after loading for a while, it display a alert i.e "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

So how can i nevigate to iTunes update section ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have tried the following link right now but getting same result.            **http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=xxxxxxxxx&mt=8&uo=6**

Answer (score 1):

Send the user directly to your app in the store.  The "FREE" or "$" button will reflect "UPDATE".

Comment: So would you say that my answer is the correct answer to your question?  Or are you looking for an alternative solution?

Comment: Brilliant - I thought I might have been missing something.